# Como pode ser traduzido "behind the scenes"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, expressões-equivalentes, palavra-para-ideia

Ainda não encontrei uma boa tradução para a expressão inglesa "behind the scenes", não quando se refere a bastidores (de cinema ou teatro), mas com a ideia de que algo é feito sem que saibamos e sem conotação negativa.

> This is done behind the scenes.

Alguma coisa (uma tarefa, um procedimento) é feita de uma forma da qual não temos conhecimento, mas sem insinuar que está sendo cometido um ato ilegal, imoral ou, de alguma forma, indesejável.

Inicialmente pensei em "por baixo dos panos", mas já vi muitos exemplos em que essa expressão é usada com conotação negativa.

Comment: "Por baixo dos panos" realmente tem uma conotação negativa, de "escondido" por ser ilegal ou imoral ou anti-ético.  Já "nos bastidores de/do/da) é neutro.

Comment: Não é uma tradução e não serve para utilização mais formal, porém, em situações informais pode ser usado "Isto foi feito ~na moita~" pra destacar que algo foi feito escondido com uma conotação negativa.

Answer (score 11):

Uma possibilidade é:

> Nos bastidores

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas nunca ouvi (nem vi escrito) essa expressão sendo usada no contexto da minha pergunta. Acho que não é muito natural. Só me imagino usando "nos bastidores" para me referir realmente ao que acontece em bastidores de teatros, cinemas, espetáculos.

Comment: Em jornalismo político é bem comum: "nos bastidores do poder", "nos bastidores do Congresso" etc.

Comment: É assim mesmo que dizemos no Brasil: "nos bastidores".  Veja aqui (https://www.google.com.br/search?q=nos+bastidores&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=GMPXVYzqBK_X8gf4v7v4DA&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=%22nos+bastidores%22) mais de 1000 exemplos.)

Comment: Você tem uma frase especifica que está tentando traduzir? Talvez haja outra opção, dependendo do contexto. @EricCarvalho

Comment: Aliás, acho que o uso figurado é até mais comum que o literal.

Comment: @Centaurus O que eu mais vejo nesses resultados são títulos (de artigos ou livros), também não é isso que estou procurando. Me refiro a algo desse tipo: "[How port allocation is done behind the scenes in zmq?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31921057)". Já faz tempo que vejo construções como essas e acho meio estranho dizer "Como a alocação de portas é feita  nos bastidores no (ou do) zmq?".

Comment: @EricCarvalho  "nos bastidores do..."   Pode usar que todos entenderão.  Não acredito que exista uma tradução melhor.  Em tempo, "port" pode ser porto, orifício, portinhola, mas nunca vi o uso como "porta".  Eu traduziria como "locação de portos" ou "demarcação de portos" mas precisaria saber mais sobre o contexto.

Comment: @EricCarvalho Você pode dizer apenas "como a alocação de portas é feita no zmq?"

Comment: @Centaurus Neste caso a porta é [essa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_%28redes_de_computadores%29) ;). Certo, na verdade não é uma porta, mas é assim que falamos no Brasil.

Comment: Ou "como funciona de fato a alocação...."

Comment: @EricCarvalho  Ah, nesse caso eu retiro o que disse.  Não sou analfabeto em informática, mas também não sou perito no assunto.

Answer (score 4):

A minha sugestão é **debaixo do capô** ou **sob o capô**. Isto é uma tradução direta do inglês **under the hood**. Não encontrei esta expressão em dicionários estabelecidos, mas ela aparece neste [Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/under-the-hood):

> A metaphorical area that contains the underlying implementation of something - e.g. a piece of hardware, a piece of software, an idea, etc.

E o que acontece debaixo do capô também não se vê, portanto isto parece-me corresponder ao pedido na pergunta. Curiosamente não encontrei nenhum dicionário que atribuísse esse significado a [*behind the scenes*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/behind+the+scenes).

*Debaixo do capô* tem a vantagem de não ter qualquer conotação pejorativa. Pelo contrário, debaixo do capô do automóvel está o motor, e o que quase todos os motoristas querem é que ele continue a funcionar sem problemas, e que não seja nunca necessário levantar o capô.

A frase que o OP tinha em mente é ficaria portanto:

> How port allocation is done behind the scenes in zmq?
>
> Como é que a alocação de portas é feita debaixo do capô em zmq?

*Debaixo do capô* já  pode até ser encontrada na internet. Encontrei [este artigo sobre o Google](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/google/17989-debaixo-do-capo-google-revela-como-funciona-o-seu-sistema-de-busca.htm); Este outro [da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb286986(v=vs.120).aspx), a poucas linhas de distância usa *sob o capô* e *nos bastidores*; e mais [outro sobre o Firefox](https://tecnoblog.net/89857/firefox-10-download/). O contexto em que a expressão é usada nos três artigos parece ser esta: nós temos este software bestial a funcionar debaixo do capô sem ninguém o ver; vamos abrir o capô para ver como aquilo funciona.

Comment: Esses usos são traduções literais da construção em inglês, talvez até automáticas; pra mim não são suficientes para afirmar que "sob o capô" seja usado em português.

Comment: Tens razão. O meu "já é usado" é demasiado forte. Mas para mim não é sequer necessário que alguém tivesse alguma vez usado _debaixo do capô_. Desde que a expressão seja entendida com o significado pretendido e soe bem, eu usá-la-ia.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o termo certo para "behind the scenes" é

> por detrás das cameras

Answer (score -1):

Acho que dependendo de qual for o sentido da frase vc poderia usar apenas "a fundo"
I wanna know how things work behind the scene/ under the hood
Eu quero saber como as coisas funcionam a fundo